# Unity Buttons On click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

Hi so I have 4 buttons in a prefab I have a plus button a - button which I have set up so that when you click the + button it should edit the text in 2 of the other buttons to say Sell 10 and Buy 10 and when you click + again it will say Buy 20 and Sell 20 etc.

These buttons have been set up by adding a c# script to the main prefab and using the on_click function of the + and - buttons. The problem I am having is what is the best way to change the text of the other 2 buttons. As this prefab will be dynamically created to make 100-200x items in the shop page I was thinking of just creating 2 gameobjects in the script attached to the prefab and dragging both buttons to them but I am sure there must be a better way to just add the text components of the buttons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

I have included some images to clarify:

[image]
[image]

What I am looking for is the best practice so that when the + or - is clicked it updates both the buy and sell buttons to go from 10 to 100 or vice versa. This is a prefab and will be cloned 200-300 times so looking for the way to do this that will have the best performance.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow you; is your question about a good practice to handle state-changes in UI, such as changing the text in a button on some event?

Comment: I have uploaded some images and a statement to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I usually map UI to variables in a neat way. Let me know if you have any questions, if you want it further tailored to your solution you'll have to show me some of your code and how it works today. This is the generic concept I usually use:

```
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Text sellButtonText;

    private int _sellAmount;
    public int SellAmount
    {
      get
      {
        return _sellAmount;
      }
      set 
      {
        _sellAmount = value;
        _sellButtonText = "Sell " + _sellAmount;
      }
    }


    void Start() 
    {
      _sellButtonText = GameObject.Find("The Object with Sell button").GetComponent<Text>();
    }
}
```

You expose a variable SellAmount to public, anyone who changes that variable will also change what is displayed in the UI by using custom getters and setters.

If you're unfamiliar with this architecture, and why we need a private _sellAmount as well, it's to avoid infinite loops. The get and set-methods need to store their data in another variable since if the get-method returned the same variable it would enter the same get-method again... and again... and again. Same with set, it'd set the same variable, which goes in to the same set-method, which sets the same variable, which goes in to the same set-method. To solve this you store it in another, private, member.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I forgot to add in using unityengine.ui then i can make a public text and drag the text of the buttons on to it.